# How to prevent Mongoose findOneAndUpdate to add ObjectId automatically

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a collection with the following document

```
{_id:'12345',account:{ba:0,br:0,ac:0}, scores:{a:0,b:0}}
```

I have a resolver and after running it

```
const input = {account:{ba:1,br:2,ac:3}, scores:{a:1,b:1}} 
const profileId='12345'
const res = await modelProfile.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: profileId }, input);
```

it finds the document and properly changes it but it is adding also **_id** to each object there :

```
{_id:'12345',account:{_id:'46456',ba:1,br:2,ac:3}, scores:{_id:'4645677', a:1,b:1}}
```

How can I prevent mongoose from automatically adding _id to the SUBDOCUMENT objects of the document that they don't have ObjectId already. (as you saw, the document has ObjectId but objects inside as subdocuments does not have it)

Comment: use `{ $set: input }` instead of direct input, second just off `_id: false` in your schema.

Comment: Thanks dear @turivishal

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I should change schema

```
var subSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    // your subschema content
}, { _id : false });
```